# Symfony3 add executables in bin directory

Tags: php, symfony

developing a Symfony3 app and installing some liberalise like phpunit, behat they get installed in vendor/ dir which is perfect but I would love to have the exacutable for these libralies in bin/ dir.

I looked at composer.jason and i seen i can add this:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
```

but this unfortinally does not create exactable short cut in this dir.

Any idea how i can achieve this

Comment: Remove `/vendor` directory and rerun `composer install`

Comment: @maximkou wow thx buddy hehehe worked perfect :)